# Why is my ngFor loop not recognizing the property inside the object?

Tags: angular

I keep getting an undefined for my property which lies inside the object. The ngFor is able to recognize the rest of the strings inside of the array, but not the property which is within the object. How do I get ngFor to recognize the property?

I don't want to alter the array which contains the object since I have seen this done before with the results I am looking for. For some reason my code is not able to display the property of the object.

Parent component user-list

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-list',
  templateUrl: './user-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-list.component.scss']
})
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
names: any ;


  constructor() {
    this.names = [{title:'Ari'},{title:'Carlos'},{title:'Felipe'},{title:'Nate'}];
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Child component user-item

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-item',
  templateUrl: './user-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-item.component.scss']
})
export class UserItemComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() name: any;

  constructor() {



   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Parent component user-list html

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let name of names">
    <app-user-item [name] = "name"></app-user-item>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Child component user-item html

```
<h1>
Hello {{name.title}}
</h1>
```

When I try the code name.title I get an undefined. Instead of undefined I should be getting a list with Ari and Carlos, because they are both values of the key title inside of the object.

How do I get Ari and Carlos to display using name.title in my child component html?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: `this.names = [{title:'Ari'},{title:'Carlos'},'Felipe','Nate'];` Why are Felipe and Nate a string and not wrapped into an object as Ari and Carlos?

Comment: Because I was testing to see what the loop does and does not identify. It can identify felipe and nate by merely using {{name}} but the moment I try {{name.title}} I get an undefined.

Comment: And for the record, I've tried wrapping all the names in objects, and I still get an undefined.

Comment: Can you try and replicate on StackBlitz? I tried with your example but couldn't replicate the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hvh9h1

Comment: Here's an example that works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ptxnp9

Comment: Wow I figured it out. in my app.component.html I had both <app-user-item> and <app-user-list> displaying. For some reason when I got rid of <app-user-item> in my app component.html the list of objects is no longer undefined.

Answer (score 0):

use `{{name?.title}}` and correct syntax of `this.names` array of object

```
this.names = [
    {title:'Ari'},
    {title:'Carlos'},
    {title:'Felipe'},
    {title:'Nate'}
];
```

Comment: What exactly did the name? syntax do and why does it now recognize the property inside of the object?

Answer (score 0):

In your child html.

```
<h1>
Hello {{name?.title ? name.title: names}}
</h1>
<!-- we need to use ternary operator bcs in your array is contain a object as well as direct value -->
```